# How can I have a static function inside a template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm not very good with C++ but I'm trying to create a generic base class that can be extended to create a kind of dynamic enum. There may be way better ways to do this and I'm open to suggestions but my main question here is why am I getting the error `C2338 The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type`.

**Base Enums Template Class**

```
template <typename T>
class Enums
{
public:
    BOOL HasValue(T enumValue) const
    {
        auto it = this->m_EnumPairs.find(enumValue);
        return (it != this->m_EnumPairs.end());
    }

    const DWORD Count() const
    {
        return this->m_EnumPairs.size();
    }

    const DWORD &operator[](T enumValue) const
    {
        auto it = this->m_EnumPairs.find(enumValue);
        if (it == this->m_EnumPairs.end())
            return 0;

        return it->second;
    }

    const DWORD GetVersionCode() const
    {
        return this->m_VersionCode;
    }

    static const DWORD Count(DWORD versionCode)
    {
        T derived(versionCode);
        return derived.Count();
    }

protected:
    DWORD m_VersionCode;

    Enums(DWORD versionCode) : m_VersionCode(versionCode), m_NextValue(0) { }
    virtual ~Enums() { }

    void Add(T enumValue)
    {
        for (auto it = this->m_EnumPairs.cbegin(); it != this->m_EnumPairs.cend(); it++)
        {
            if (it->first == enumValue)
                throw std::exception("Enum key already defined");
            if (it->second == this->m_NextValue)
                throw std::exception("Enum value already exists");
        }

        this->m_EnumPairs[enumValue] = this->m_NextValue++;
    }
    void Add(T enumValue, DWORD value)
    {
        this->m_NextValue = value;
        this->Add(valueName);
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<T, DWORD> m_EnumPairs;
    DWORD m_NextValue;
};
```

**Derived Enums .h**

```
namespace Test
{
    typedef enum _Enum
    {
        EnumValue1,
        EnumValue2,
        EnumValue3,
        EnumValue4,
        EnumValue5,
        EnumValue6,
        EnumValue7,
        EnumValue8
    } Enum;
}

class DerivedEnum : public Enums<Test::Enum>
{
public:
    DerivedEnum(DWORD versionCode);
    ~DerivedEnum();
};
```

**Derived Enums .cpp**

```
DerivedEnum::DerivedEnum(DWORD versionCode) : Enums(versionCode)
{
    this->Add(Test::EnumValue1);
    this->Add(Test::EnumValue2);
    this->Add(Test::EnumValue3);
    this->Add(Test::EnumValue4);
    this->Add(Test::EnumValue5);
    this->Add(Test::EnumValue6);
    if (versionCode > 200)
        this->Add(Blocks::EnumValue7);
    this->Add(Blocks::EnumValue8);
}

DerivedEnum::~DerivedEnum()
{
}
```

**Usage**

```
Enums<DerivedEnum>::Count(250)
```

I'm know I'm doing something wrong, I just want to know what I'm doing wrong and how I can do something like `Enums<DerivedEnum>::Count(250)`. The error centers around the static `Count` function and the error goes completely away when I remove the static function and the call to it.

**EDIT**

To answer a question asked in the comments: The usage of this would be to get the size or number of entries in the "enum". For example, if I needed to read a structure from a file and in that structure is an array of items:

```
struct DataFromFile
{
    int flags;
    int array[SIZE_OF_ENUM];
}
```

If I have different versions of this file that contain a different number of items in the array, I can use the "enum" class to determine how many bytes to read based on `Enums<DerivedEnum>::Count(250)`. If that doesn't make sense, I'll try to clarify even further.

**UPDATE**

As ZDF said in the comments, changing `unordered_map` to `map` fixed the issue. `unordered_map` requires a `hash` function and the default does not know how to hash my custom class, `map` does not require a hash and therefore works perfect in this situation.

Comment: Just a small and unrelated not on your usage of returning constant values from functions: It's pre4tty much useless. Returning a constant *reference* makes sense, returning a constant value does not. If the user of the function wants to assign the value to a constant variable then that's okay, you don't have to return a constant for that to work, instead it will make it problematic for the user of your function to assign it to a non-constant variable.

Comment: As for your problem, can you please show us more details on how you use the static function? Where do you use it? How do you use it? From where do you call it? And the error message you show, that's all the compiler tells you, it is complete?

Comment: `why am I getting the error C2338 The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type` Perhaps that's because the C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type. Did you want to ask "I think the C++ standard should provide a hash, why does the compiler think otherwise"? Or maybe "what's a hash and why does C++ think I need one"?

Comment: From your error message it looks like you are using the template with a type that it is not hashable. Change the unordered map to std::map and see if it works.

Comment: By the way, you might want to read more about [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) and learn how they are related.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the note on const, I'll stop using it for anything other than pointers and reference types.

Comment: @n.m. No, I understand the text in the error and I know what I hash is, I'm wondering why I'm getting that error with my implementation.

Comment: @ZDF That fixed it!! Changing it to a `map` instead of an `unordered_map` fixed the problem. It compiles, runs and works correctly. Add an answer and I'll accept it. Also, could you describe why a `map` works vs an `unordered_map`?

Comment: [unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Examine the template parameters.

Comment: @n.m. Okay, that makes sense then. It works for the enum because `std::hash` has a specialization for all enums but in my static use case I'm passing a derived class as the template parameter which isn't an enum or any of the supported types for the default `std::hash`. Thanks.

Comment: _"Add an answer and I'll accept it."_ It's fine. I do not have time for an elaborate answer.